# FastAPI: passing path params via included routers

Tags: python, fastapi, path-parameter

In symplified case we've got a projects and files. Files belong to projects. Every of them has their own router to perfom CRUD actions via API.

So, in code it should look like this:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, APIRouter

app = FastAPI()

projects_router = APIRouter()
files_router = APIRouter()

app.include_router(projects_router, prefix="/projects")
projects_router.include_router(files_router, prefix="/{project_id}/files")

@files_router.get("/")
def list_files(project_id: int):
    # Some code, that list all project's files by project_id
```

But the `list_files` function can't get `project_id`. How can it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `project_id` as a [path parameter](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/path-params/). By default it's a [query parameter](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params/).
Three dots `...` in `Path` parameter make it required:

```
from fastapi import Path
@files_router.get("/")
def list_files(project_id: int = Path(..., gt=0)):
    # Some code, that list all project's files by project_id
```